# Front end libraries for angular 2 based projects

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Basically, I am a Laravel developer and currently learning angular 2 framework. I have been managing my third party front end assets via bower. Here is the sample of my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "Bower Components",
  "dependencies": {
    "titatoggle": "https://github.com/kleinejan/titatoggle.git#~1.2.6",
    "tinymce": "git://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-dist.git#~4.1.10",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.37",
    "jquery-toast-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "Sortable": "^1.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#^4.7",
    "bootbox.js": "bootbox#^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

It saves the above dependency into the public/vendor folder of my laravel project setup. In the base template or view, I had been referencing it like shown below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("vendor/jquery-toast-plugin/dist/jquery.toast.min.css") }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("vendor/titatoggle/dist/titatoggle-dist-min.css") }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css") }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css') }}" />
```

It was just simple! If you need to integrate new feature, add to the dependency, run bower install, add reference tag and it's done.

But Angular 2 has different story and architecture. It prefers to manage all its dependences through npm package manager. It is modular. I really like the freedom of separating front end from the back end as it will allow us to develop a common back-end application for both web app and mobile app. Ok I am going off topic here. Let's come to the point.

At the meantime, I couldn't find any alternatives for the front end libraries that I am using. Some of the libraries such as titatoggle, eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery-toast-plugin, Sortable which are really cool stuff are missing in the npm repository. Can you suggest any alternatives or recommendation that fits into the angular2 convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Angular 2 and Bootstrap a very solid proposal for a datepicker would be https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker. It is a fully-native directive which means that you wouldn't need to bring jQuery etc. Obviously it is available on npm and support Angular2-specifics like AoT and server-side rendering with universal (something that is very hard with jQuery-wrapped widgets).